# Credit Card Testing on prodution

Tags: automated-testing

I'm working on automation project for ecommerce site.

I usually run a mass checkout on production after each release.

- Place **1000** orders
- Use **Cash-On-Delivery** method
- Use a **test account**

But some countries (e.g Singapore) don't prefer Cash-On-Delivery so most of their products do not accept this method. And of course I cannot access production database to make a query :)

Is their anyway to use Credit Card for testing purpose on production ?

Comment: Didn't understand. Could you please elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application's payment provider.

Some providers have a set of designated test credit card numbers that you can use against their production gateway. These will process as though they are normal credit cards but no actual payments will be made.

Others have a test gateway that you can connect to and run all your tests against.

Others will provide you with a simulator to connect to.

In the latter two cases you would be testing in production prior to taking the application fully live by switching to the production payment gateway. In the first case, you'd be testing live in production.

Some other factors I've run into with testing payment gateways and applications that use them:

- Payment gateways that allow test card numbers are rare.
- Testing gateways are not necessarily active all the time. You may have to arrange with the provider to have the test gateway available for release testing.
- Testing gateways can have bugs that don't occur in production.
- Testing gateways often have special amount conditions to allow applications using that provider to check all the possible responses from the payment provider (e.g. an order total ending in .01 will return a payment declined message)
- Simulators are even more likely to have bugs that don't occur in production.
- Simulators are often not updated when the production payment gateway is updated. This could mean that some supported card types aren't available via the simulator where they are available live.
- On the positive side, simulators often include detailed logging of payment requests and responses.
- Some simulators can be configured to allow specific card numbers.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I'll investigate about payment provider

Answer (score 0):

I am little doubtful about whether this scenario can be automated. I will first answer about Credit card testing on production environment:

**iOS:**

- When you are testing for iOS, You need to configure the sandbox account.
- Sandbox provides virtual but secure test environment for real life scenarios for purchase.

**Android:**

- When it come to android app, there is no provision like Sandbox as per my knowledge
- You need to crosscheck using test credit cards but only till payment. It also have few limitations
- We can not checkout 100% end use customer scenario

**Should we automate scenarios like checkout?**

- There might be different opinions. But we could prefer automate those scenarios which will keep user in our/targeted app
- In this checkout process, there will be few alerts or pop-ups and screens which might belongs to other app or outside our targeted app
- We have limitations of getting access to those elements to control & perform action using our framework. Would be great to test these scenarios manually.